# &nbsp when I use ENTER for skipping line

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor, post-editor, line-breaks

I don't know why when I'm using "Enter", that add `&nbsp;` in Pages/Posts Editor. That doesn't matter, but on my website, when I look the code `&nbsp;` makes this code :

```
<p> � </p>
```

and � appears on my website...

How can I change that to simple code :

```
<p> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `&nbsp;` with the trailing semicolon. Not without, maybe that's the problem?

**edit:** also the question is quite hard to understand. Do you add those `&nbsp;`s by hand or is the editor adding them even though you don't want them or what?

Comment: Yes, it's &nbsp; with semicolon, sorry. When I'm editing text and I just tap on ENTER without writing something, that makes <p> � </p>, and I would like that becomes <p> </p> but if I'm tapping something after skipping line, that's right : � doesn't appear

Comment: updated : I just need to change <p>�</p> to <p></p>

Comment: Well yeah but that's very strange. When I hit enter it doesn't add anything but a line break in editor, not any content. Does it still do this if you disable all plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I needed :

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Erase "�" */
function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('�', '&nbsp;',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content')
?>
```

I put in plugins, and now that's ok !

Mhhh not really …  I think it's a encoded problem.